# Merge two database to each other?

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have question about merge two or three database(SQL Express).
I have a project that any facility have own databases and every year these databases should merge with each other.
My problem is how can I merge these databases? what software can do it?

Comment: What do you mean that the databases should union with each other? Do you mean they should merge and all have the same data at the end of the year?

Comment: SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare by Red gate are good data base tools for copying/merging data. http://www.red-gate.com/

Comment: What are the PK for the tables, how large is the DB, do you have Visual Studio pro sith database tools installed

Comment: Could Red gate can merge two .mdf file without connection string Bobby?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare by Red gate are good database tools for copying/merging data. http://www.red-gate.com/

Comment: they are good tools but if they are using SQLExpress i would be surprised to see them spring for RedGate. Have you used the compare tools that are in VS2013? any thoughts?

Comment: I used to work with Redgate but it need connection string. Here we have two ore tree .mdf file. I have no connection string.

Comment: I believe you can create connection strings that reference .mdf tables that are not attached to servers.  I've never tried it, though.